# How to get a tableau dashboard into a webform that is part of a Visual Studio Project that I have hosted on AWS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, tableau-api

I want to display a Tableau dashboard in a web form in a visual studio project that I have hosted on AWS. I have used C# to code. I don't even know where to get started with this!

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it's a bit hard to answer, but if you can show your data publicly and it isn't very large in size, you could put your visualization on Tableau Public, then link directly to the URL in your web form.

Comment: Perfect thank you that gives me some direction (its not large in size just 4 graphs that came from a small Microsoft SQL database)

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as accepted - I'm trying to get my reputation high enough to upvote!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an iframe in your project to display your visualization.
check out below link to embed your view in your project.

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm